# combination, shortest path algorithms and Python

Tags: python, algorithm, combinatorics

I don't know much in codding but understand basic Python.
I wanted to challenge myself by writing a program that will solve the next - 
Considering a store is giving you 3 options - X$ per day, Y$ per month or Z$ per year, which combination is the best for me assuming I want T amount of time?

Now, as far as I can understand, I have here a basic combinatoric question for creating a tree of combinations, and a need of some shortest-path algorithms (Djikstra, Bellman-Ford..?) for finding the best option ("Shortests","less expensive")

Please help me find from where I need to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an instance of multiple item [**knapsack problem**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), where your time is the weight, and the "value" is the cost. Your knapsack size is the amount of time you want. In here you want to minimize the value, which is equivalent to maximizing the negatives (Assume a day "costs -X, month -Y, year -Z).

This can be solved by the following recursive formula (assuming costs are integers or can be brought to be integers), and can be implemented rather efficiently using [Dynamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming).

```
D(0,0) = 0
D(x,0) = INFINITY   x>0
D(x,i) = INFINITY x < 0
D(x,i) = min{ D(x,i-1), D(x-time[i],i) + cost[i] }
```

---

EDIT: Note that this is not an instance of shortest path problem (not directly anyway), because you have a restriction on the path, you want to find a path that takes M days, and shortest path algorithms struggle with such restrictions.

Comment: Many thanks Amit - I though that by knowing the whole combinations (and for instance, filtering which combination is bigger then M days..) I can input to the algorithm the correct paths.. but I guess it is smarter to use the knapsack problem.